# Why does the context.sync keep looping when used in Office.js?

Tags: javascript, office-js

When using context.sync in a Word add-in using Office.js, the code starts to loop continuously. If I take out the return context.sync() the looping stops. I have similar code in a OneNote add-in that does not loop. Only this Word one does.

I have already tried commenting the line out or taking parts of the return statement out with no luck. Maybe I don't know how this syncing works? Again, it only happens in Word.

```
function getHTMLcontent() {

 // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
    Word.run(function (context) {

        // Create a proxy object for the document body.
        var body = context.document.body;

        // Queue a commmand to get the HTML contents of the body.
        var bodyHTML = body.getHtml();

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
        // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync().then(function () {              
            html = bodyHTML.value;
            // console.log("Body HTML contents: " + html);
        });
   })
}
```

This chunk of code is used to run the method when a user types:

```
doc.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, 
    function(eventArgs){
    getHTMLcontent();
});
```

Comment: please see updated code. user action triggers the getHTML()

Comment: Even if I run the method using a jQuery click, same looping happens